# Angularjs changing route param

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change route parameter without causing a post back in my application which is using Angularjs. My route definition is:

```
.when('/VoucherGrid/:id', {
                controller: 'VoucherController',
                templateUrl: '/Content/app/forms/VoucherEdit/header.html'
    })
```

I am trying to change the route parameter `id`:

```
$route.current.params.id = response.data;
```

Also I tried to use this method:

```
 $routeParams.id = response.data;
```

But still it is not working. I can read previous parameter value as well but it does not change as I set it to the new value in a callback function in my controller. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you just `location.path('/vounchergrid/' + response.data)`? Changing the route from underneath angular seems strange because it uses the route to do thing.

Comment: Yes, this would be a solution, but I thought I could avoid rewriting the Url in my code and just changing the route parameters by name which I think is more abstract and cleaner.